# Почему среди функций mb_ нет аналогов функциям ucfirst(), lcfirst() и др?

Tags: php

Почему среди функций `mb_` нет аналогов функциям `ucfirst()`, `lcfirst()` и др?

В сети очень много решений, например:

```
mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8'); // Аналог ucwords()
```

Но штатные функции `mb_ucwords(), mb_ucfirst()` и `mb_lcfirst()` были бы весьма полезны... Вселенский заговор разработчиков PHP или в отсутствии `mb_ucfirst()` и `mb_lcfirst()` есть какой-то смысл?

Comment: Я считаю правильно группировать функции по типу выполняемых операций и аргументом передавать какую именно операцию вы хотите совершить. Все эти ucfirst() появлялись во времена когда php еще не был нацелен на ООП.

Comment: Вот представь что ты пишешь большой проект и надо в том числе выполнять ряд операций над строками, ты будешь под каждую такую операцию писать отдельную функцию, или пытаться таки группировать с передачей аргументов?